# is Rails 5 redirect_back method a security vulnerability?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, ruby-on-rails-5

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html

```
Redirects the browser to the page that issued the request (the referrer) if possible, otherwise redirects to the provided default fallback location.

The referrer information is pulled from the HTTP `Referer` (sic) header on the request.
```

Wouldnt someone be able to simply change the referrer header to a malicious website? Does Rails have any sort of prevention measures for this?

Comment: "Wouldnt someone be able to simply change the referrer header to a malicious website?" - and infect themselves?

Comment: If a end-user wants to set his own `referer` header to a malicious website then make your app redirect it to "back", then this same end-user will end up on this malicious website. In french we call this "shooting in your own foot"

Comment: haha you have a point. There would need to be some XSS going on for someone to change someone else's header. @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be easy to say you can only hijack yourself, so it is not vulnerable. But it is a bit more complex than that.

The referer header in the request is technically user input, which should not be trusted. However, obviously there is some control over this as referer should be set by the browser and it is not supposed to be overridden by some malicious website. There are circumstances when referer can in fact be faked. For example if a malicious browser plugin is used, like an old vulnerable version of Flash or Java - both could do this at some point afaik. Or a malicious browser extension. Or the originating client is not a browser and hence such protection on referer does not apply.

Maybe these are not applicable to your scenario, but if referer was safe, it would also be adequate for csrf protection, which it is not (or at least not recommended).

It is about defense in depth. Maybe you don't exactly know how this would be exploited, but in many cases it's betfer not to have this weakness. Having said that, `redirect_back` may be ok in many scenarios, while it is not ok in many others. Your threat model should cover this too.